# Vapor - Route with Basic Auth always returning 401

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

I'm new to Vapor and I've implemented register and login routes. Register works fine. Every time I call the login route it seems to have a problem. Every time, I try to login with a registered user using Basic Auth it just returns 401. Attaching my code below.

App user model:

```
extension AppUser: ModelAuthenticatable {
    static let usernameKey = \AppUser.$email
    static let passwordHashKey = \AppUser.$passwordHash
    func verify(password: String) throws -> Bool {
        try Bcrypt.verify(password, created: self.passwordHash)
    } 
}
extension AppUser: JWTPayload {
    func verify(using signer: JWTSigner) throws {
    } 
}
```

Routes configuration:

```
   //MARK: Unprotected API
    let unprotectedApi = app.routes
    try unprotectedApi.register(collection: AppUserController.Unprotected())
    //MARK: Password Protected API
    let passwordProtectedApi = unprotectedApi.grouped(AppUser.authenticator())
    try passwordProtectedApi.register(collection: AppUserController.PasswordProtected())
```

login logic:

```
    extension AppUserController.PasswordProtected: RouteCollection {
    func login(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Response> {
        let user = try req.auth.require(AppUser.self)
        let token = try req.jwt.sign(user)
        let loginResponse = AppUserLoginResponse(user: user.response, accessToken: token)
        return DataWrapper.encodeResponse(data: loginResponse, for: req)
    }
    func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {
        routes.post(Endpoint.API.Users.login, use: login)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you edit your question to include how you are calling the login route that results in the error, please?

Comment: Your login route presumes your user is already logged in because it is in the protected group. It would normally be unprotected and there isn't any code showing the actual login using `request.auth.login(User(name:)`

Comment: So how should I proceed then? To take email and password and search in the db if user with this hashed password exists?

Comment: Usually, yes, I'll post an example.

Comment: ok, I'll be grateful!

Comment: How you've done it is fine, at least for the log in function. How do you authenticate the log in request and how are you registering the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `login` route as it stands is returning 401 because you have included it in the protected group, which requires the user to be logged in already. It would normally be unprotected. You need some code to do the logging in. This function assumes the user is identified by an email address and has supplied a password somehow:

```swift
private func loginExample( email: String, password: String, on: req Request) -> EventLoopFuture<Bool> {
    return AppUser.query(on: req).filter(\.$email == email).first().flatMap { user in
        // user will be nil if not found, following line test for this
        if let user = user {
            // user was identified by email
            if try! user.verify(password: password) {
                // password matches what is stored
                request.auth.login(user)
                // login has succeeded
                return true
            }
        }
        // login has failed - because either email did not match a user or the password was incorrect
        return false
    }
}
```

I've kept it simple by forcing the `try` in the call to verify (avoiding do-catch, etc.). You need to use something like this code in your login route, perhaps decoding the email and password from an HTML form.

Comment: The original login method is fine. It uses an HTTP Basic Authentication middleware to handle the auth so should work. I suspect they'll get the same error with your solution too

Comment: @0xTim, where is the call to `req.auth.login`?

Comment: It's in `AppUser.authenticator()` - that maps through to https://github.com/vapor/fluent/blob/main/Sources/Fluent/ModelAuthenticatable.swift#L45 in the middleware which is called if the credentials are right

Comment: Hey! Can you check my other question I posted a couple of minutes ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68739465/vapor-updating-user-property-returns-precondition-failed-id-exists